# How to delete all the local database in the J2ME application

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, rms

I want to refresh my J2ME application means I want to delete all the local db which the mobile contains. I know how to do above task in android application by "Clear Data" by using this we can delete all the data from my android application same thing I want to do in J2ME application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In J2ME Environment, 
you can achieve such thing by listing all the RMS Using following method.

```
public static String[] listAllRecordStore () 
{
    return RecordStore.listRecordStores();
}
```

Here, Method Returns the String array, now delete one by one RMS table in a for loop.